# Website language translation in PHP (SQL)

Tags: php, sql, arrays, echo, translation

i want to implement in my website a language translation. For this is created a table "translations" in my database:

```
id | de    | en    | other languages    
1  | Hallo | Hello | ...
```

Based on this i have added the following query into my header:

```
 if ($user['language'] == 'de') {
        // Select prepared PDO 
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, de FROM translations");
        $result = $statement->execute(array());
        $text = $statement->fetch();
    }

if .... other languages
```

I want to show the text translation based on the user language. I am wondering if there is a simple php echo method i can use now. As explained above i have the translation in the table available but whta is the easiest method to echo it?

For example. Current state:

```
<h4 class="...">Hallo</h4>
```

New state with translation (of course its not working):

```
<h4 class="..."><?php echo $text['en'] ?></h4>
```

So what i am missing is a simple method to adress the id (row) to this text output which is in that example "1".

As a possible method i found this example:

```
<?php
$age=array("Peter"=>"35");
echo "Peter is " . $age['Peter'] . " years old.";
?>
```

I think i can use that and it looks from text size as efficient. But i am not sure how to modify the query for my table above. Best would be i can do somethink like:

```
echo $text['1']
```

and it shows the text output: "**Hallo**". And in case:

```
echo $text['2']
```

it will show "**Hello**".

What do you think about this method? And can you help me please to modify my query to get this method working ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your questions under my first answer i decided to add another solution - easier without functions etc.

Fetch all translations in single query with fetchAll:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, de, en FROM translations");
$result = $statement->execute();
$textsRaw = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Your `$textsRaw` will look like this:

```
$textsRaw = [ 
  ['id' => 1, 'de' => 'Hallo', 'en' => 'Hello'],
  ['id' => 2, 'de' => 'auf Wiederschauen', 'en' => 'Good bye'],
];
```

Now we transform `$textsRaw` into `$texts` with easier structure:

```
$texts = [];
foreach ($textsRaw as $text) {
  $texts[$text['id']] = $text[$user['language']];
}
```

Now `$texts` look like this:

```
$texts = [1 => 'Hello', '2' => 'Good bye'];
```

If you have this, then translating is as easy as doing:

```
echo $texts[1];
echo $texts[2];
```

If you access translation id that doesnt exist you will get normal php notice: `PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in ....php on line ...`

Comment: Great! This is working well and without function fitting to my demands! I appreciate this answer :) Many thanks for this! 

In a earlier post you recomment to use not the ID as indicator to have a better overview later in the source code. I agree with you. Its more or less really difficult later to find something or i need to comment each text echo. I thinki will implement some kind of a key word to have a better overview. I can do this with your code example now by my self! Many thanks again!

Comment: While this works, please note: This is a slow and resource intensive way of doing it, which is difficult to maintain long term. This will be slow in implementation and maintanance for as long as you use this :)

Comment: @Martijn its not. Please consider other information in this thread. Its a tradeoff between simplicity of solution and efficiency. Also it depends on how many translations are on the page. Fetching 300 translations in 1 query vs 50 queries for each translation per request? I would still advise fetching all and caching it to file/redis or whatever if it begins to be a problem, but it is out of the scope of the question. Please take note that author wanted to avoid usage of functions. Also "This will be slow in implementation" - can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. Now it's 300 translations, but what if your site grows to 1000 or 2000? A few extra pages might jsut do that. Or what if instead of a few small translations, you now store the content of pages per language? Pushing that all into an array will not be a good plan and is a waste because instead of 1, you now have ALL languages in memory. This also loads *all* translations always, even if you say only need the contact page. Also, looping through all that data? That will make everything worse :)

Comment: And to be honest, IMO not wanting to use functions is not a reason. Then learn those, functions are one of the most *basic* things you can learn. One might even argue more important than DB skills

Comment: @Martijn So you propose separate query for each translation?
Looping through 300 elements is not the end of the world. Did you even read the part about caching? I would also recommend YAGNI here. Its not difficult to ask another question if performance starts to be an issue, but it is not the case here.

Comment: Dear Blahy and Martijn, based on my requirements, my project structure and of course my personal demands i was looking for a solution. 

Using a function is absolutely recommend and nothing is wrong on that... in general! But considering my post and request, I feel comfortable by using just the "non function" method. In my project i only use procedural php code, no oop, no functions. I did this on: Total : 217 files, 48396 codes, 3112 comments, 12013 blanks, all 63521 lines. I want to keep this method and my code strategy where i am "home".

Comment: You are correct! I defenetly need to have a deep dive on functions. But at the moment i dont need theem. I think this is a interesting discussion between a.) skills, b.) method c.) ressources.

I an tutorial for this topic i am sure both of you would use "functions". Its the most common way. Blahy already proposed this method in hin 1st answer. How ever... releated to my demands the answer without function is personaly for me and helps me out of my dilema. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Offtopc: Please do yourself a favour, spent 5minutes learning functions. You will thank you :) The basics are **very** easy to understand and will pay itself back in time in no-time. And im not talking OO, just basic functions.

Comment: Absoltely! I like this discussion. I think this is very usefull for next newbs who are looking for translation method. I do now following: I will implement the translation method on my landig page. At the moment the loading time is 450 ms. I will add all tranlsations in my table. and will measure it again. I will tell you the result and the effect.

Answer (score 1):

I once solved it like this, I didnt want to select al the data as I though that would be a waste of resources. The solution I came up with was (IMO) quite elegant:

Have a variable the the language in it, eg `$language = 'NL'`. Then, use in the select:

```
SELECT description_{$language} as description FROM example
```

If you fetch that, you can simply use `$result['description']` in the language you want :)

That requires minimal effort for your queries. You can make a function with `['title', 'description']` as input which returns it in the format as it is in the query, that way you keeps your queries a bit smaller:

```
function langCols($columns){
    $lang = 'NL'; // implement your language logic here
    $transColumns = array_map(function(string $column){
        return $column .'_'.$lang.' AS '.$column;
    }, $columns);
    
    return implode(', ', $transColumns);
}
```

Please note that this was the solution for my case, but with minimal effort it should fit your need aswel

Comment: Thank you for reviewing this. I will go with the solution from Blahy because this is without 'functions' and is on my skill level I think your solution can be used aswell if functions are prefered. True the full fetch can cause high ressource assumption but in my case i am talking about max. 300  rows. I will check the function method if my server reaction time is showing me some bad result due to this.

Comment: You can do it without function, just use the query.

Comment: Also, feel free to vote if you think it's useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch all translations in single query with fetchAll:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, de, en FROM translations");
$result = $statement->execute();
$texts = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Your `$texts` will look like this:

```
$texts = [ 
  ['id' => 1, 'de' => 'Hallo', 'en' => 'Hello'],
  ['id' => 2, 'de' => 'auf Wiederschauen', 'en' => 'Good bye'],
];
```

Now you cant do this with simple echo construct, but you can define function like this:

```
function t(int $key): string {
  global $texts;
  global $user;

  $translationTexts = array_filter($texts, function(array $text) use ($key, $user) { return $text['id'] === $key; });

  if (count($translationTexts) !== 1) {
    throw new Exception('Unknown text key: '.$key);
  }

  return reset($translationTexts)[$user['language']];
}
```

Now wherever you want to translate you just do: `echo t(1);` or `echo t(2);` and based on user language it will output translation, example:

```
$user = ['language' => 'en'];

echo t(1);
echo t(2);

$user = ['language' => 'de'];

echo t(1);
echo t(2);
```

And output:

```
Hello
Good bye
Hallo
auf Wiederschauen
```

And if you use some nonexistent translation id, like `t(3);` you will get exeption: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Unknown text key: 3`

It would be better to have Translator service/class but i think this simple version is better for starters.

Also you can think about using one of the languages as the translation key (or even introduce new column as translation key), so it is more descriptive: `echo t('hello')` - this is easier to track in source code than `echo t(1)`.

Comment: Thank you for this! I have tried to run the code but there is an error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unknown text key: 50 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Auditmanager\2.php:99 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Auditmanager\2.php(105): t(50) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Auditmanager\2.php on line 99`

The query is working. I have checked with print_r. It loks like tehre is an issue with the function. To be honest i do not have much knowledge about functions to solve that problem. Do you see some misstake or do you need furter informations? By the way: id 50 is available in the table.

Comment: Is it normal that you switch sometimes from texts to text in the function?

Comment: @MischaMilivojeBakic maybe you have 2 rows with id 50? It definitelly looks like you either dont have row (translation) with id 50 or you have more than one

Comment: @MischaMilivojeBakic take a look at my new answer - maybe it will be more clear for you. And if the problem with translation id 50 remains - post the contents of $texts